# Background gamma radiation

Tags: radiation, gamma-rays

There are plenty of lists of sources of general background radiation, but can anyone reduce that list to the major contributing sources purely for background gamma radiation (specifically low energy, x-ray-ish level)? I'm more interested in measurements in Curies, rather than Sieverts if possible.

Thank you

Comment: Gamma rays are, practically by definition, extremely high energy, high frequency electromagnetic waves.  Therefore, to ask about "low energy, x-ray-ish" gamma rays is like asking for square circles.

Comment: If he's simply making the distinction between photons (represented with a $\gamma$ at all energies in particle-physics) and massive particle radiation, the meaning is clear.

Comment: On the other hand, buzsh does have a problem with his units request. Curies is not a dose. It's just a count of events per unit time (and the SI unit of activity is the Becquerel with $1 \,\mathrm{Ci} \approx 3.7 \times 10^{10} \,\mathrm{Bq}$). Sieverts is a measure of biological damage from radiation. They are not at all the same thing. There is no general conversion for $\mathrm{Ci}$ to $\mathrm{Sv}$, and to define one for a particular case requires you to specify radiation type, radiation energy and absorption profile. None of which we have.

Comment: @Sean: There is no clear cut-off between X-ray and $\gamma$ ray in the EM spectrum, just "somewhere" in the upper MeV range. So saying "low energy, x-ray-ish$ isn't really much of a problem (though it'd be more clear with a statement like *with $E\in[10,400]\,\rm MeV$*)

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I was thinking radio wave instead of x ray when I read the question.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating why you care about the distinction  (gamma vs other, and energy range) - and what "plenty of sources" you have found that you cannot yourself reduce to the list you ask for? Also -- a Curie is a curious unit to use - it is as though you are asking for "how many tons of Co-60 exist in the universe" rather than "given the amount of radiation at a certain point, what equivalent source strength at a distance of 1 m would produce the same amount of radiation". As I said - perhaps a bit more background will help generate a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is, perhaps easier to catalog the non-photon sources and leave the addition and unit conversion to you.

- The cosmic background is almost entirely muons.
- If you spend times in building with non-trivial radon level, that does it largely alpha.
- Most (but not all) of the natural radiation background is gamma, but it runs a wide range of energies for a few $\mathrm{keV}$ up to more than $1 \,\mathrm{MeV}$.